# Print view header using the "Twig Tweak" module

Tags: views, 8, theming

I would like to print out the header for a view, but not the rest of the content using the [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module. I've tried variations on `{{ drupal_view('VIEW_NAME', 'PAGE_NAME', 'view_header') }}`, but that prints out the entire view.

Comment: just `{{ drupal_view('VIEW_NAME', 'PAGE_NAME') }}` print the view with the header.

Comment: @berramou – OP wants only the header.

Comment: twig tweak provide only two extension for views, `drupal_view` and `drupal_view_result` and no one of the did this, i think you shoud develop you own twig extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have create simple extension for that:

1. add the following to `MYMODULE.services.yml`

```
    services:
      MYMODULE.twig.render_view_header:
        class: Drupal\MYMODULE\Twig\HeaderView
        tags:
          - { name: twig.extension }
```

2. Create `HeaderView` class inside `MYMODULE/src/Twig`.
3. Copy the code from [HeaderView.php](https://gist.github.com/BERRAMOU/7068c04318904921288967199fda39c8)
4. Clear cache.
5. In your twig call the extension like:

```
{{ render_view_header('VIEW_NAME', 'PAGE_NAME') }}
```

Comment: this is awesome! At line 67 in `HeaderView.php`, I'm looking at my xdebug output all all of the info for the view is `null`. There's no values for header, footer, etc. If I go into `$view->storage` I can see the values for the view. Going to `$view->storage->getDisplay('default')['display_options']['header']['area']['content']['value']` actually gets me the value for the header, but is obviously not good code (also the `global replacement tokens` no longer work). Any clue on what the function would be to get the values, rather than null?

Comment: if `$headers = $view->header;` is null so you have no header added to your view, did make sure in the views ui that you have a header added ?

Comment: yes, I have a header added, and I tried adding a footer and that also didn't show up. Every value for the view is either null or false in my xdebug. It's the correct view, and like I said if I go into storage it shows the correct info, but none of it is available at the `$views` level.

Comment: https://imgur.com/ZdJ6HqD here's a small screenshot of my xdebug output. Things like `header` are further down and null as well.

Comment: the header and footer directly under `ViewExecutable`  not `ViewExecutable-> storage` ?

Comment: can you dump `$view->header` ?

Comment: `/var/www/html/SITE/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Debug.php:60:null`. Like I said, everything under `ViewExecutable` is null or empty.

Comment: i have edit the code try now ?

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks @berramou. I gave you an upvote but it doesn't display since I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: it's okay, i'm glad that help, you can improve it and add another extension for the footer if you need it, good luck.

Comment: I actually altered the function to accept 3 arguments, with the 3rd being the element you want to render, and renamed the function to reflect that because I figured it would be more useful generalized!

Comment: Cool, good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Main twig template for the **views** is `views-view.html.twig`. You can see **header**,  **footer**,  **content** , **attachment** variable in this file.So you can print your views in your method `{{ drupal_view('VIEW_NAME', 'PAGE_NAME') }}` then rename `views-view.html.twig` to `views-view--VIEW_NAME--PAGE_NAME.html.twig` and remove unwanted content.